# How do you read a file specified as a parameter to a function when running GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm using ghci 6.10.4 at the dos command line in XP, and also in emacs using haskell-mode-2.4

When running programs that operate on stdin, is there a way I can redirect a file to be stdin? For example if I have a function called main that reads from stdin, I can't do:

```
*Main> main < words.txt
```

Is there another way?

Also I would like to be able to type stdin into the ghci window, which seems to work, but what is the EOF key? I thought it was Ctrl-D but that doesn't work.

Comment: I believe in dos/windows Ctrl-Z is the EOF key...

Comment: Ah yeah. I tried that and thought it failed, but does in fact work, but then as the answer below states, it also closes stdin  and you get an error message like :
*Main> <stdin>: hLookAhead: invalid argument (Bad file descriptor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be easier if you rework your `main` to open the file itself.

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
      [] -> doStuff stdin
      file:_ ->
        withFile file ReadMode doStuff

doStuff :: Handle -> IO ()
doStuff = …
```

```
*Main> System.Environment.withArgs ["main.txt"] main
```

Don't give a EOF on stdin while within GHCi.  If you do, all further attempts to read from stdin will fail:

```
Prelude> getLine
*** Exception: <stdin>: hGetLine: illegal operation (handle is closed)
Prelude> getContents
*** Exception: <stdin>: hGetContents: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

Comment: On Cygwin, CTRL+C seems to cancel an operation while also closing the file handle? How do you cancel the operation without closing the handle?

Answer (score 4):

You CAN type :main in GHCi to invoke command line parameters.  I'm afraid you'll probably just want to use that.

Comment: +1 Whoa, when'd they add that?  That's definitely shorter than `…withArgs…`

Comment: That's handy but you can't redirect stdin like this:

    :main < words.txt

Comment: Sorry ephemient, but I haven't been using haskell long so it's been here as long as I can remember. And justinhj, why not try this? main = do { args <- getArgs; let file = head args; contents <- readFile file; hPutStr stdin contents; ... } Then you can do :main words.txt