# Input redirection in WinGHCi

Tags: haskell, winghci

I know I can do the following from a command prompt:

```
$ runghc WC < quux.txt
```

How do I do this in WinGHCi?  I know I have to first load the file like this:

```
Prelude> :load WC
```

But then what?  This doesn't work:

```
*Main> WC < quux.txt

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: data constructor `WC'

<interactive>:1:6: Not in scope: `quux'

<interactive>:1:11: Not in scope: `txt'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you route stdin from a file to a function when running GHCI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735386/how-do-you-route-stdin-from-a-file-to-a-function-when-running-ghci)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the IO routines provided:

http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html

Another place to look is:

http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html

I think you need to write your program differently. WC should be parameterized by the file handle. Then you can do `wc (openFile "quux.txt" ReadMode)` at GHCi. Then you define your main function as `main = wc stdin` to keep the input redirection at the command prompt working.

Comment: Pleased to meet you :)